# Data types in .Net versus data types in Motorola PLC?

Tags: .net, microchip

Can anyone help for getting the list of all the datatypes of motorola PLC.

Thanks,

Khan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motorola's PLC is a logic controller (ie a computer chip), so it has no concept of datatypes

It has an instruction set, which makes use of registers to store values, and operates on a single type of data binary. These binary values can be interpreted as integral values, or floating point values, depending on the type of controller family.

Datatypes are higher level abstraction used by programming languages, which will get translated into a group of instruction set operations with corresponding binary values.

In theory, you could use a .NET language to write software for a Motorola PLC, if you had the appropriate compiler.

For reference, see the linked pdf for the instruction set for the Motorola 68000 family. You'll notice that the only datatypes are register values, and constants. It's up to the compiler to translate the high level language (aka compile) into the native instruction set.

[68000 Instruction Set](http://www.tigernt.com/onlineDoc/68000.pdf)